# rsyslog configuration

Tags: logging, rsyslog

I need some help :< Does anyone know how i can change the log severity ?

What i want to do is somethink like this.

node3 -> intermediate -> logserver

I want in the intermediate node to filter logs based on some keywords and afterwards send them with different severity on logserver.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do a "shell execute" which calls a script that modifies the severity and uses [`logger`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/logger) to send it back.

From `man rsyslog.conf`

> Shell execute
>          This executes a program in a subshell. The program is passed the
>          template-generated message as the only command  line  parameter.
>          Rsyslog waits until the program terminates and only then contin‐
>          ues to run.
>
> ```
>    Example:
>           ^program-to-execute;template
> ```
>
> The program-to-execute can be any valid executable. It  receives
>          the template string as a single parameter (argv[1](http://linux.die.net/man/1/logger)).

Comment: I don't want to use logger. It should be changed inside .conf {because it's an intermediate node}.

There is nothing like that {Just talked with the developer}. The only way to do it is by using the template as you said, but it's not trivial how  can i do it !
For the moment i 'm using a sniffer and try to match the messages of logger with my forwarded logs, in order to be parsed correctly from the server, but no luck :<